# Printing bash commands to a logfile as they execute

Tags: bash, function, command, printf, logfile

Here's what I have so far:

```
LOGFILE="/home/bubba/bubba.log"

# Function to echo commands to log file as they are executed
exe () {
  params = $@  #Put command-line into "params"
  printf "%s\%t\%s\n" "$params" >> $LOGFILE #Print date, a tab, and command to run
  $params  #Run the command-line
} #End of exe() function

exe rm -rf /usr/Library/bubbasfile.txt
exe rm -rf /usr/Library/bubbas add-ons/
```

The first call to exe, which has no spaces, works as I would expect it to work. 
The second call to exe, which has a space in the path, does not work.

I've tried putting double-quotes around this, and around that, and around the other thing, and around everything; I've tried a backslash escape character before the space; I've tried a double backslash before the space. Some of these permutations result in the correct line being printed to the log file, but the directory with the space in it never gets deleted.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Do you know `script` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Long answer: when you store the arguments in `params`, you lose the distinction between spaces within arguments vs. word breaks between arguments. Solution: use an array instead, and then refer to it using the idiom `"${arrayname[@]}"` (double-quotes are critical!), which'll convert each element of the array into a single "word" even if it contains spaces. Printing the arguments to unambiguously is also a little tricky, but printf's `%q` format can do it.

Here's my suggested rewrite (with a few other cleanups, like removing spaces around the `=`):

```
# Function to echo commands to log file as they are executed
exe() {
  params=("$@")  # Put command-line into "params" as an array
  printf "%s\t%q" "$(date)" "${params[0]}" >> "$LOGFILE" # Print date, a tab, and the command name...
  printf " %q" "${params[@]:1}" >> "$LOGFILE" # then the arguments (with quotes/escapes as needed and spaces between)
  printf "\n" >> "$LOGFILE"
  "${params[@]}"  #Run the command-line
} # End of exe() function
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't understand this yet, but I'm chewin' on it. (I also am not quite getting the results I expect (no newline in the log file between commands), but that may be due to a typo in my copying your code; I'll work on it.

Yeah, my code snippet above had a couple of typos that aren't in my real code (like the spaces and the extra %s), but I very much appreciate you fixing them; it helps me as a green bash-coder to solidify some of the concepts in bash coding.

And I very much appreciate your overall response! Thank you!

Comment: So, when the arguments are sent, say "rm file1 file2 with spaces file3", you're saying the $@ variable (which I have concluded means "all the command-line", despite google not verifying that for me) knows the difference in the space between arguments vs the space within an argument, but that when it's put into my own variable "params", that distinction is lost?

Comment: Oh, not an extra "%s" in my original snippet, but a missing "$(date)". Wow, errors are easy... ;-)

Comment: @DebianFanatic: Check my corrected answer; I had an off-by-one error in the array indexing (bash array indexes start at 0, not 1, so my original answer left the actual command name out of what was printed). As for documentation, look around [Greg's BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), Gnu's [bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), and the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). Also, google's generally useless searching for symbols; try [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=bash+%24%40) instead.

Comment: I see you made a small change to your rewrite (changing "${params[@]:1:1}" to "${params[0]}" to separate out the first argument (the command name)); I've incorporated that change into my code.
My newline printf was being ignored; I deleted that line and retyped it; apparently I had typo'd some hidden-character keystroke into that line which was causing it to be ignored.
I also had to escape the space in my calling command, so that "exe rm -rf /usr/Library/bubbas add-ons/" became "exe rm -rf /usr/Library/bubbas\ add-ons/".
But it works! And I thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on symbolhound.

I see in your link that you suggest using "set -x" instead of "putting code into a variable" like what we're doing here. I had tried that, but ran into some issue, but that was two days ago, which I've thoroughly forgotten. I think maybe it was that I couldn't figure out how to redirect the output to a file instead of just to the terminal window. I think I also disliked having the "set +x" show up in my output.

Thanks, again! You've been a HUGE help!